# Remove Filename from string in Lua

Tags: string, lua

I need cut off the .ogg from the end of a various strings

For example

```
v = bdorian.ogg
h = {}

h[1] = v
```

How could I cutoff '.ogg' from the end of string v?

(A quick google search yielded no help)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can take everything before the last period

```
v = "bdorian.ogg"
h = {}
h[1] = v:match("(.+)%..+$")
```

Comment: This match does not return filename if there's no an extension! In that case it returns nil.